# What do you recommend: a Widescreen display or a higher-res display?

Tags: best-practice

I am currently using an old 1920x1080 21.5" display, and I find it very hard to make high-res designs on it.

While searching for a display that will suit my needs better while still being under 300$, I found two kinds of displays and I'm not sure which one's better.

On the one hand, 2K displays are a respectable step-up from 1080p, and they often come with bigger screens, which is a plus. 
On the other hand, Widescreen displays can store more information and help me multitask or drag-and-drop files from another screen, but cheap ones are still 1080p vertically.

What do you think is better? A 2K display? A Widescreen? Maybe a curved Widescreen? Also, could you link to a display you like that's in the neighbourhood of 200$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No-one can decide for you; you need to weigh up the pros & cons for your own use-case. Also, 'shopping requests' are generally off topic right across Stack Exchange, as recommendations are short-lived & often only have relevance to the original asker.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately hardware recommendations are off-topic here on GDSE. Better I think to use some product review sites on the internet instead.

Comment: Any Dell IPS 24" will work fine and probably around the 200$.

Answer (score 1):

You have some misconceptions.

If your monitor is 1920x1080 the only difference is that you will see things smaller, but at the same resolution, or if you see it closer to you it will be the same angular resolution as one bigger monitor further away. But I understand your point.

Widescreen displays do not store more information. No display does, they only... display.

> Drag-and-drop files from another screen

No. Drag and drop is a feature of the operating system or an application, an additional display only display. It is only a bigger monitor split into two or more.

---

Said that, a 27" 16:9 display at 1920x1080 px is still good resolution and at good prices. A 24" is good enough to view a letter sized paper (or A4) at real size in vertical position.

Some people want to use a 27" monitor at 1440 vertical px, but if your computer has not a good GPU you can push a bit your computer capabilities. The same with an ultra-widescreen 21:9 or more.

If you stay on one application most of the time, you do not need a widescreen. If you are making, for example, web design coding on one application and viewing results on a web browser you probably will benefit from a widescreen. But if you want to use dual monitor, probably it is too much.

But that is all up to you and how powerful your computer is.